# Find line count of a file in HDFS to compare with the count present in QC file

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have a data file and qc file loaded in HDFS and I want to compare the count present in QC file and the data file line count. For this, I wrote a shell script which extracts the count part of the QC file and does `wc -l` for Data file.

**For QA file:**

`qccount=$(webhdfs -cat hdfs://${CLUSTER_NAME}$hdfs_src_path/$directory/$qc_file_name | cut -d "|" -f2)`

`echo "QC file count: $qccount";`

This prints out the count as 256341

**For data file:**

`file_count=$(webhdfs -cat hdfs://${CLUSTER_NAME}$hdfs_src_path/$directory/$data_file_name | wc -l | cut -d " " -f1)`

`echo "File count: $file_count";`

This prints out 0

Here wc -l for the file in hdfs is not working may I know the reason?

Comment: Is it possible that your data file has no `\n` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like this:

`file_count=$(hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://${CLUSTER_NAME}$hdfs_src_path/$directory/$data_file_name | wc -l)`

`echo "File count: $file_count";`

Note: I am not sure why you have used `webhdfs -cat` instead of `hdfs dfs -cat`

Comment: hdfs dfs is called as webhdfs here. I tried the same thing but the count is coming as 1 which is not the actual count of the file.

Comment: The commands above should work if you have `\n` separating all the lines. Can you send the dummy data & QA files?